# How to position Google map to particular position?

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps

I have three map canvases on three different divs. In the javascript I have set the centre to the same position in all three. But the second and third do not get that centre. What could be the problem?
Any ideas please?

```
var centerPosition=new google.maps.LatLng(6.924782, 79.863643);
function initialize() {
    var map_canvas1 = document.getElementById('map_canvas1');
    var map_canvas2 = document.getElementById('map_canvas2');
    var map_canvas3 = document.getElementById('map_canvas3');
    var map_options1 = {
      center: centerPosition,
      zoom: 8,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

var map_options2 = {
  center: centerPosition,
  zoom: 8,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

var map_options3 = {
  center: centerPosition,
  zoom: 8,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
map1 = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas1, map_options1);
map2 = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas2, map_options2);
map3 = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas3, map_options3);

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using 'center' property in JSON object, you can also set the center position of each map.

Please try below code after instantiating the map object

```
 map1.setCenter(centerPosition);
 map2.setCenter(centerPosition);
 map3.setCenter(centerPosition);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Please refer to the jsfiddle. Your code is working fine
http://jsfiddle.net/2mw6b/
var centerPosition=new google.maps.LatLng(6.924782, 79.863643);
function initialize() {
    var map_canvas1 = document.getElementById('map_canvas1');
    var map_canvas2 = document.getElementById('map_canvas2');
    var map_canvas3 = document.getElementById('map_canvas3');
    var map_options1 = {
      center: centerPosition,
      zoom: 8,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

var map_options2 = {
  center: centerPosition,
  zoom: 8,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

var map_options3 = {
  center: centerPosition,
  zoom: 8,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
map1 = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas1, map_options1);
map2 = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas2, map_options2);
map3 = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas3, map_options3);

}
initialize();

**Html code**
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v3&libraries=places,drawing&sensor=false"></script>
<div id="map_canvas1" class="mapCont"></div>
<div id="map_canvas2" class="mapCont"></div>
<div id="map_canvas3" class="mapCont"></div>
**Css**
.mapCont{
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}
```